# Deleting first line from a text file using RandomAccessFile

Tags: java, randomaccessfile

I want to delete the first line of text file using RandomAccessFile class.
My Input file "bulkwfids.txt"
has the data as below:

```
234567
345578
455678
566667
```

Expected output needs to be(first line deleted):

```
345578
455678
566667
```

But the actual output I am getting is as follows:

```
78
56
345578
455678
566667
```

Could someone please clear the doubt.
Here is the code snippet that I have written:

```
 import java.io.*;
 class DeleteLine
 {

            public static void main(String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
            {

               RandomAccessFile raf = new     RandomAccessFile("C://Users/hp/Desktop/bulkwfids.txt", "rw");
               raf.readLine();

            int n=0;
            for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
            {
            byte [] buff = new byte[100];
            raf.read(buff);
            raf.seek(0);
            raf.write(buff,n,6);
            n=n+6;
            raf.readLine();


            } 


            raf.close();                
}

}
```

Comment: I think the problem is that you are assuming that each line has six bytes, when actually it has eight.

Comment: Don't do that! Write the new contents to a new file and then rename to the old file.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight how can it be 8? there are 6 digits in one line.I tried with 8 digits,but now I am getting o/p as:
     67      345578
     455678
     566667

Comment: @ghostrider There are also one or two characters at the end of each line to mark the end of the line. I assume this is a class assignment. Does the assignment specifically say that each line will always be six or eight characters?

Comment: @Kenster - One or two characters, depending on the "style" of the file.